# Azure CosmosDB compression options

Tags: azure, compression, azure-cosmosdb

We are planning for a larger CosmosDB install .. storage costs are excruciating. For a 105Tb CosmosDB service that's a $26k monthly bill, which is a 99.9% cost of that estimate.

Are there any ways to tier storage? Add compression? Any other recommendation for a larger CosmosDB installation like this? As it stands now, this would be a no-go for the project and we will be looking at alternatives.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question is going to get closed as it is a product recommendation so will use comments.   Are you actively querying all of this data regularly or does recency play a role here? If it does, take a look at analytical storage in Cosmos and TTL older data off. Way cheaper. Can also query the data using SQL or Spark on-demand when needed. If you need to query all of it, you can use symbolic property names that map to proper names in your data model classes.

Comment: @MarkBrown thanks for the quick reply.. chances are we need all of it. Can you please send a link to documentation on using symbolic property names? If you could add your answer separately and this solves the issue, I will be gladly to accept it. Thanks again

Comment: We don't document it but it's very simple. Build POCOs with regular property names and then use an abbreviation or small # of characters using the json property attribute in your data models. For example, if I had a very long property name, I could map it to a smaller property name like this, [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "foo")].

Comment: This really is open ended and there is no way to give an objective answer but… if you’re not querying certain properties (e.g. long form text for a product review, or maybe encoded binary image ), move it out to something like blob storage and reference via URI. That’s a very common pattern .